# Destroying child window without parent WIN32 APi

Tags: winapi

I have one problem . I am trying to destroy child window ,but it also destroys parent window, so application closes. 
I have such code.

```
HWND cloneWin =FindWindowEx(hWnd, 0, szChildWin, 0);
        if (cloneWin) {
            MessageBox(NULL,"You are trying to create more than one child window\n Current child window will be destroyed", "Message", MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION);
          DestroyWindow(cloneWin);
        }
```

What is wrong ?
THx in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632682.aspx) says:

> A thread cannot use DestroyWindow to destroy a window created by a different thread.

Since you are trying to find these windows using `FindWindowEx`, it seems pretty obvious that the windows were created in a different process, never mind a different thread. In other words, your call to `DestroyWindow` can never succeed. Hard to know why this is bringing the other application down, but since you are not obeying the rules then I suppose it is reasonable that anything can happen.

It's plausible I suppose that you could send the window a `WM_CLOSE` message and hope that it will respond by calling `DestroyWindow`. That would be a valid call to `DestroyWindow` because it would be made on the thread that created the window. But it all depends on how that other window responds to `WM_CLOSE`.

Comment: Thx for reply, I have just tried
 SendMessage(cloneWin,WM_CLOSE,0,0); But it also destroys all application ((

Comment: Guess you are out of luck. Why don't you try a less aggressive approach. All the same I do believe I've your question.